# getServletConfig() / getServletContext() returning null value

Tags: java, servlets, servletconfig

I want to get `servletContext` in a Java class to read a file from `WEB-INF` directory. I extended my class with `HttpServlet` and tried to get the context as in the below code, but the servlet config is returned as null. I don't use any jsp or controller. My intention is to read a file directly placed in the `WEB-INF` directory from a Java class. Please let me know how I can get not null `servletConfig` / `servletContext` in the class:

```
ServletConfig config = getServletConfig(); 
ServletContext context = config.getServletContext(); 
InputStream resourceContent = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/samplefile");
```

Comment: Where is this code in your servlet? Is it in ctor? You will get config only in methods which are inherited from `HttpServlet`: `init, doGet`, etc.

Comment: just because it extends from HttpServlet it does not mean it's a servlet being started and managed by the container. Can you post the whole servlet code?

Answer (score 26):

Trap for young players. If you override the

```
public void init(ServletConfig config)
```

method, you must call

```
super.init(config);
```

inside the method. Otherwise the superclass sees the context as `null.` It's mentioned in the Javadoc:

> When overriding this form of the method, call `super.init(config).`

NB You can get the context directly via `getServletContext().` There's no need to go via `getServletConfig().`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am accessing the ServletContext in a plain java class which is a non-web component i.e. the final layer of the application. There is not front end for the application. Any thoughts on how I can access ServletContext without the web layer?

Comment: You can't. A `Servlet` only runs in a servlet container.

Comment: @EJP: Did you mean `init(ServletConfig config)` instead of `ServletContex contextt`? The document @EJP mentioned can be found [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29).

Comment: @MahsaMohammadkhani Thank you, yes.

Comment: This young player was trapped! Thank you

Comment: So this was my secret to staying young.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it turned out the web.xml file was created in the wrong place and was not being loaded by the container.

It needs to be created in the root of the WEB-INF folder. Ideally let Eclipse do this for you when you create the project.

Comment: You didn't get a null `ServletContext` because you had a file in the wrong place. You are describing a different problem.